# JButtons and Mouse Listeners or Action Listeners

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton, mouselistener

I am making a little game of math, which consists of creating a random numbered sequence of numbers between 1-9 or 10-99, then separating the number > 10 and then create a sequence out of it. Example, I have 4 numbers to generate, I generate 1, 3, 5, 10. Then I separate the number 10 and concatenate the numbers together like this : 1 3 5 1 0. Now the objective of the game is to reassemble the numbers together to get the sum. So I'd have to click 1, 3, 5, then 1 and 0 while keeping the mouse pressed to obtain 10. Finally I check the sum pressed in with the original sum to find if it's the right answer.

Anyways, I have some trouble with the MouseEvent and the buttons. First I created the numbers randomly, then put them in an int array. After that, I take that array and switch it into a String so I can put them on a Button. Then, when I create my button, I get the String and I do a String.charAt(i) to get a single digit of my sequence. I add my MouseListener on the button and then add my button to the panel.

I would like to get the value of the digit on my button when I press that button. I tried getSource(), getText() or other methods, but it didn't work. Should I use ActionListener for this or MouseListener?

Here's some snippet of my code:

```
fixedSequence is the String version of the number sequence
GameLogic is the class where I do the logic of the game
sequencePanel is the JPanel that shows the buttons of the sequence
```

Creating the int array sequence:

```
private void createSequence(int cutNumber) {
    //cutNumber is the number of digits in my sequence
    for(int i = 0; i < cutNumber; i++) {
        numberSequence[i] = numberGenerator();
    }

}
```

Creating the String array out of my int array:

```
private void sequenceToString() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for(int value: numberSequence) {
        builder.append(value);
    }

    fixedSequence = builder.toString();

}
```

Now to create the sequence with buttons:

```
    private void createASequenceButton(char c, Container container)  {

        JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(c));
        button.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        button.addMouseListener(new SequenceButtonListener());
        container.add(button);

    }

    private void addNumberSequence() {
        //GameLogic is where I create the number sequence and where I do the
        //logic of the game
        for(int i=0; i < GameLogic.getFixedSequence().length(); i++) {
            createASequenceButton(GameLogic.getFixedSequence().charAt(i), 
                                                    sequencePanel);
        }

    }
```

Now for the MouseListener part:

```
private class SequenceButtonListener implements MouseListener {

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {

       //This is where I want to get the value in int or string of
       //the button I pressed so I can do my calculation with it            

    }

}
```

I'd like some opinion on the way I did it, if I could do it an easier way or it's only possible with ActionListener instead of MouseListener.

Thank you for your time,

Carl

Comment: A button click is handled by an ActionListener, not a MouseListener.

Comment: I tried ActionListener, how I would go on about it? Like when I want to add both buttons together to form a number out of digits. I'd use MousePressed -> MouseReleased? Or it can all be done in ActionListeners

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817283/how-to-make-one-actionperfomed-on-a-jbuttin-matrix-java/33817303#33817303 for a working example.

Comment: `then 1 and 0 while keeping the mouse pressed to obtain` - well you can't click two buttons while keeping the mouse pressed. Guess I really don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I'll try and find a way with ActionListener!

Comment: Again an event will only be generated for one button at a time using an ActionListener. If you want to combine two MouseEvents, maybe you can use a MouseListener and then you will also need to handle a meta key (like Control) to determine if the MouseEvent was generated when the Control key was held down. This would indicate you want to combine the previous event with the current event. This is the approach used when selecting multiple items from a JList or JTable, for example.